# Filter array of array (substring)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of array and I want to show only array with the substring from a search bar.

My code :

In the first part (not show) I get value from search bar and had a space before (to see all arrays if nothing is write)

```
 const Arrays = [
 [
  { text: " first ", image: "1.jpg", },
  " hello"," world"," ",
],
[
  {text: " second",image: "https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png",},
  " goodbye"," world"," ",
],
[
  { text: " Salut", image: "bass.jpg", },
  " Ca va"," au revoir"," ",
],
];

const showArrays = Arrays.filter(function(array) {return array.includes(searchimp) })
```

That is my filter fonction, it work only if searchimp was exactly same with an element from an subarray

With searchimp my const from search bar.

At end I have a function (not show) to show "showArrays" and format each first element from each array to show pictures and there alt

It run, when I write "goodbye" it return the second array but when I write "goo" it did'nt return anything.

Comment: Use `array.some()` instead of `array.includes()`. Then you can provide a function that does the kind of match you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for a substring, you can use the `indexOf` method.

To bypass a nested array, it is better to use the `some` method

```js
const Arrays = [
  [
    { text: " first ", image: "1.jpg", },
    " hello"," world"," ",
  ],
  [
    {text: " second",image: "https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png",},
    " goodbye"," world"," ",
  ],
  [
    { text: " Salut", image: "bass.jpg", },
    " Ca va"," au revoir"," ",
  ],
];
const searchimp = prompt('What find? ')
const showArrays = Arrays.filter(function (array) {
  return array.some(el => { // iterate
    if (typeof el === 'string') { // search in string
      return el.indexOf(searchimp) > -1; // if find, return true and stop iterate
    }
    return false;
  })
})

console.log(showArrays);
```

One line record

```
const showArrays = Arrays.filter(ar => ar.some(el => typeof el === 'string' ? el.indexOf(searchimp) > -1 : false))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.some()` to look if there's a match. Do the match with `String::includes()`:

```js
 const Arrays = [
 [
  { text: " first ", image: "1.jpg", },
  " hello"," world"," ",
],
[
  {text: " second",image: "https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png",},
  " goodbye"," world"," ",
],
[
  { text: " Salut", image: "bass.jpg", },
  " Ca va"," au revoir"," ",
],
];

const searchimp = 'goo';
const showArrays = Arrays.filter(arr => arr.some(elem => typeof elem === 'string' && elem.includes(searchimp)));

console.log(showArrays);
```